# user_id in other table does not get value in one to many relation in laravel

Tags: laravel-5, one-to-many

In restaurant table, foreign key do not get value of user table. I make relation one to many in user and restaurant tables. user can have many restaurants.

```
class Restaurant extends Model
{
    protected $guarded=['user_id'];
    protected $table ="rest_info";

    public function menus() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Menu');
    }
    public function dishes(){
        return $this->morphMany('App\Dish','dishable');
    }
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User','id','user_id');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to access these relationship with in your controller function you can use **with** keyword of laravel you have to something like this:-
If you wish to get the menus you can use something like this in your contoller Function

```
$getResturantdata = Resturant::with('menus')->get();
dd($getResturantdata);
```

If you wish to get the menus and users both you can use something like this in your contoller Function:-

```
 $getResturantdata = Resturant::with('menus','users')->get();
dd($getResturantdata);
```